# in linux file permissions, what is the number besides the permissions?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

What does the number besides the permission represnet? i.e. the 3, 8, and 1's.

[image]

Also, is there a command that combines chown and chgrp ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use chown with the group after the user like so:  `chown user:group`.

The number you mention is the number of [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to a file.  It's always at least 1 (itself).

Answer (score 4):

The number is the number of links to the inode.  Directories have two (.. and .) plus the number of subdirectories (each one has ..).  Files have N where N is the number of hard links, where all files have at least one.